# C++, Jumping Sprite, Collision

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I'm trying to implement very basic platform/sprite behaviour using C++.

So far I have successfully rendered 2 platforms and a sprite which can move and jump. Below is a snippet of code that simulates the jump and gravity.

If I comment out lines `2,3, & 6` from the snippet commented "//gravity", I can not jump through the platform from underneath perfectly, but I'm unable to land on it... If I leave them as they are below, (Using the `check_collision` function), I can successfully jump up and onto a platform and move along it left and right. Unfortunately, if I press jump again (`key119`), I fall through the platform and sometimes even stick to the underneath of it instead of doing another jump.

What am I forgetting to implement to allow the sprite to do another jump?

```
    if(keyDown[119]){                                               //While 'w' key is pressed and not colliding
        if(!check_collision(sprite,platform)                        //If not colliding...
            && !check_collision(sprite,platform2)){
            y_Pos += jumpHeight;                                    //Jump up
            if(keyDown[97] ){x_Pos -= velocity*jumpLength;}         //While 'w' and 'a' are pressed, simulate arc of jump/gravity
            if(keyDown[100]){x_Pos += velocity*jumpLength;}         //While 'w' and 'd' are pressed, simulate arc of jump/gravity
        }
        else                                                        //Else you must be colliding, bounce off
            y_Pos -= jumpHeight;
    }
    if(keyDown[115]){y_Pos -= velocity;}                            //While 's' key is pressed
    if(keyDown[97] ){x_Pos -= velocity;}                            //While 'a' key is pressed
    if(keyDown[100]){x_Pos += velocity;}                            //While 'd' key is pressed

    //gravity
    if(y_Pos>0){                                                    //If above ground
        if(!check_collision(sprite,platform)                        //And not colliding
            && !check_collision(sprite,platform2)){
            gravity-=5*delta;                                       //Calculate gravity force
            y_Pos+=gravity;                                         //Descend to ground
        }
        if(keyDown[97] ){x_Pos -= velocity*2;}                      //While off ground, whilst 'a' is pressed, move left
        if(keyDown[100]){x_Pos += velocity*2;}                      //While off ground, whilst 'd' is pressed, move right
    }
    else{gravity=0;}                                                //Else, on ground, so gravity force is zero
```

Please excuse my naivety and do be patient, I am self learning and we all have to start somewhere. Thanks.

There's too much code to post the whole program, but if you're interested, the full source code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/VGg1RXAF)

Comment: "If I comment out lines 2,3, & 6 from the snippet commented "//gravity", I can **not** jump through the platform from underneath perfectly, but I'm unable to land on it... " is "not" supposed to be "now"?

Comment: No, it's supposed to be not, ie, If commented out, I bounce straight off the underneath of it and return to the ground without going through it. But if i jump from the side, up and on to it, i fall straight through. Sorry, I'm terrible at describing things.

Comment: What is the type of `y_Pos`?  int?  double?

Comment: They are floats @DrewDormann

Comment: @Reanimation it's hard to guess what all the other code is doing, but I strongly suspect that your character is falling partway through the platform.